# Ordering dynamic data rows by value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities, dynamic-data

I'm using visual studio 2010, linq-to-entities, and vb.net 4.0 to create a dynamic data site with scaffolding.

By default the rows are displayed in the order of the primary keys of the sql database, as shown:

[image]

I would like for the ones with a boolean "priority" field of TRUE to be above the others. Is there a way to do this within vb.net?

Comment: failing that I would settle for a way to format priority rows as red.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LinqDataSource, you can add `OrderBy = "priority Descending"` like below:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource 
    ContextTypeName="MyDataContext" 
    TableName="Orders" 
    OrderBy="priority Descending"
    ID="LinqDataSource1" 
    runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sort clause to your LINQ query.  If you're using query syntax then that will be something like this:

```
Dim q = From row In myTable
        Order By row.Priority Descending, row.ID
        Select row
```

If you're using function syntax then it will be something like this:

```
Dim q = myTable.OrderByDescending(Function(row) row.Priority).ThenBy(Function(row) row.ID)
```

Comment: Where would I find the LINQ query?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the data?  Are you just getting all the data from a property of your EF context?  If so then that would be equivalent to 'myTable' in my code above.  You then need to write a query, similar to what I provided above, and add the sorting clause.